# BizTalk C# Functoid Generate dynamic Dates

Tags: c#, date, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I've come across a problem a little challenge where I might need some input on how to make this possible.

In my solution I’m always going to get a specific message to trigger this. 
What I want to do is to always generate a StartDate and a EndDate, but one functoids calls each method.

So, for example if the file is received the 2016-12-20 
the Node Name EndDate gets the value ("2016-12-20 23:59:59.999999") and the StartDate then gets 2016-12-14 00:00:00.000000. 
Which is a week backwards.

Two different functoids so one method for each, we are working with the server time so we are not receiving any dates etc. 
It feels like I need to do something like this

```
    public string FormatDate(string outputFormat)
        {
            System.DateTime date;
            if (System.DateTime.TryParseExact(               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date))
            {
                return date.ToString(outputFormat);
            }
            return "";
        }
```

But cant wrap my head around this

Comment: I am not sure, but as I read your question, you want a GETDATE(), manipulate the time from this GETDATE() to 23:59:59:999 and get relative to this a 'GETDATE() - 7days' and set the time in the latter to 00:00:00:000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you generate the dates from system time you don't have to try-parse anything. You can just calculate the values from the static `DateTime.Today` property, which contains today's date at midnight local time.

Functoid 1:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);

public string GetStartDate(string outputFormat)
{
    return startDate.ToString(outputFormat);
}
```

Functoid 2:

```
public string GetEndDate(string outputFormat)
{
    return startDate.AddDays(7).AddTicks(-1).ToString(outputFormat);
}
```

By using the same startDate variable inside both functions you can make sure it doesn't skip a day in the highly unlikely case the code runs exactly at midnight.

Comment: WoW that was actually a really clean solution mate, creeds to the reply. Always cool to find new solutions from different mindes!